# Gradle and asciidoc

Tags: gradle, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am a bit confused about the options to use Gradle to convert my asciidoc files to PDF. There is this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-examples) with a set of examples using the following Gradle build file style (excerpt):

```
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.convert'

asciidoctor {
  ...
}
```

using the Asciidoctor Gradle Plugin from [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin) (github).

On the other hand we have a description of an Asciidoctor Gradle Plugin [here](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/) (official docs) or [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2014/11/awesome-asciidoctor-use-asciidoctor.html) (mrhaki) using this style:

```
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.asciidoctor'

asciidoctor {
  ...
}
```

So which one is the current (and correct) syntax? Which one am I supposed to use if I want to generate PDFs and include diagrams?

(Just to make it clear: I have only very limited Gradle experience ;)

Comment: what does your `buildscript{dependencies{}}` section look like?

Comment: It is possible that the plugin identified changed between versions. so depending on which version you're pointing to in your buildscript.dependencies, either of those could be valid.

Comment: Yes, I guess the plugin ID changed. It seems both identifiers can be used interchangeably. I will stick with the first (used in the github documentation and examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `build.gradle` reads

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.0'
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.11'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.asciidoctor'

asciidoctor {
    backends = ['pdf']
    options = [
        attributes: [
            'pdf-stylesdir': file('src/docs/theme'),
            'pdf-style': 'myowntheme'
        ]
    ]
}
```

You can use [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.asciidoctor%22) to figure out the latest versions of the artifacts within group `org.asciidoctor`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.asciidoctor'` the `org.asciidoctor.gradle.asciidoctor` is the [pluginId](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager:apply(java.lang.String)). The pluginId is picked by the plugin developer. I would use the recommendation from the official documentation.